# Git comparison of remote branches

Tags: git

I am very new to git and was trying to use the following command to compare a remote version of a branch with the remote version of develop to show the files which have differences between the two:

```
 git diff origin/develop origin/feature/xxx --name-only
```

When ran, this command showed different results for 3 different development machines and I dont understand why.

Is this command not actually doing what I think it is doing?

I actually just tried this command whilst not even connected to the remote git server and it still shows me a result when I would have expected to have got some sort of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When ran, this command showed different results for 3 different development machines

It compares against the *local* version of those remote tracking branches: it depends on *when* the remote was fetched.

To get the same result (if done on all three machine at the same time), you would need a `git fetch` first.

Comment: Thank you, that make sense, it isnt actually comparing the remote files at all.

Comment: @berimbolo exactly: it is comparing the last *local copy* of the remote (it depends when the fetch was last done)

Comment: I was just wondering is it actually possible to run a command locally that compares the actual files in the remote repository that have been pushed there or is the idea that you would always fetch first and then do the comparison?

Comment: @berimbolo always fetch. The only command which actually query something directly on the remote side (and involve a network query) is [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)